# Make echo in class in PHP

Tags: php, class, echo

i have this code.

```
$cislo1 = new Cislo(5);
$cislo2 = $cislo1->odecti(2)->pricti(5);
```

And this code.

```
class Cislo
{
  public function __construct($cislo1)
  {
    $this->cislo1 = $cislo1;
  }
public function pricti($cislo2)
{
  $this->cislo2 = $cislo2;
$cislo2 = $this->cislo1 + $this->cislo2;
}
public function odecti($cislo2)
{
$this->cislo2 = $cislo2;
$cislo2 = $this->cislo1 - $this->cislo2;
}
}
```

How i can make echo class? I think i need make echo `Cislo`. But dont know how?

Comment: Echo name of the class: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php echo class' attribute: echo $cislo1->odecti(2)->pricti(5)

Comment: If you want to be able to echo the class itself, then you need to implement the [magic __toString() method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring)

Comment: There's no instance property named `cislo1`. Also, `odecti()` method doesn't have `return $this;` so this `$cislo1->odecti(2)->pricti(5);` won't work.

Answer (score 0):

So add

```
public function __toString()
{
        return $this->cislo1;
```

And try this

```
echo $cislo1;
```

And have this
[Picture with error](https://gyazo.com/c0a615046b842c2d0170664403c93e53)